# QComboBox edit LineEdit while PopUp is active

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QComboBox` filled with some data. I wish to edit the `lineEdit` of the `comboBox` and when I do that to make the `comboBox` display his pop up while I am editing. The problem is I lost the focus of the `lineEdit` and I can write only one letter at a time.

This is what I am doing at a trivial level:

```
ui->comboBox->addItem("This");
ui->comboBox->addItem("is");
ui->comboBox->addItem("a");
ui->comboBox->addItem("comboBox");

ui->comboBox->setEditable(true);
connect(ui->comboBox, SIGNAL(currentTextChanged(QString)), this, SLOT(PrintTextLineEdit(QString)));

void MainWindow::PrintTextLineEdit(QString str)
{
  ui->comboBox->showPopup();
  ui->comboBox->lineEdit()->setFocus();
}
```

Also if I use the `blockSignal` on the `lineEdit` while I show the pop up is useless. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

It seems I need to provide some extra detail. I need to be able to write an entire word at a time without to lose focus when I use `ui->comboBox->showPopUp()` in the `currentTextChanged` signal.

Or to put it simple: the cursor do not need to disappear from the `QLineEdit` after the signal is emitted and the popUp is shown.

Comment: What kind of behavior are you actually trying to implement? Some kind of drop-down suggestion list?

Comment: Some kind of filter but without proxy or a custom list. My problem is I wish that I can type a word with the popUp open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to derive your own combo box class from `QComboBox` and override the `showPopup()` virtual method to return the focus back to the line edit.

```
void CMyComboBox::showPopup()
{
  QComboBox::showPopup();

  // Put the focus back later, after all pending events are processed.
  QTimer::singleShot(0, [this](){ lineEdit()->setFocus(); });
}
```

> As a special case, a QTimer with a timeout of 0 will time out as soon
>   as all the events in the window system's event queue have been
>   processed.

**EDIT:**

This works (although one could consider that as a hack):

```
class CMyComboBox : public QComboBox
{
  public:
    CMyComboBox(QWidget* parent) 
      : QComboBox(parent) 
    {
      view()->installEventFilter(this);
    }

    // Event filter forwards view key events to the line edit.
    bool eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
    {
      if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
      {
        QKeyEvent* keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
        QKeyEvent* newEvent = new QKeyEvent(keyEvent->type(), keyEvent->key(), keyEvent->modifiers(), 
                                            keyEvent->text(), keyEvent->isAutoRepeat(), keyEvent->count());

        QFocusEvent* focusEvent = new QFocusEvent(QEvent::FocusIn, Qt::OtherFocusReason);
        QCoreApplication::postEvent(lineEdit(), focusEvent);
        QCoreApplication::postEvent(lineEdit(), newEvent);
      }

      return false;
    }
};
```

But personally, I would probably use a separated `QMenu` for displaying word list, not the popup menu of combo box.

Comment: This is not producing any visible effect neither :(

Comment: Sorry for incorrect answer. I have found another solution based on event filter.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Each combobox has a default `QCompleter` that can show completion options in the popup. I think you can achieve what you want by setting this completers mode to `PopupCompletion`.

```
ui->comboBox->completer()->setCompletionMode(QCompleter::PopupCompletion);
```

In this case, combobox will show matching selections while typing. If you want it to list *all items of combobox*, I think you should implement a custom QCompleter that matches all items regardless of what user types.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I am looking for. I just need to type an entire word with the popUp open.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is caused by `grabKeyboard`. The keyboard is grabbed by the popups, so the solution is easy, just set the edit to regrab the keyboard, using `grabKeyBoard()`

Answer (score 0):

When I look in the code of QCombobox i see the following inside the showPopup code:

```
container->show();
container->updateScrollers();
view()->setFocus(); // <<-- focus command here

view()->scrollTo(view()->currentIndex(),
                 style->styleHint(QStyle::SH_ComboBox_Popup, &opt, this)
                         ? QAbstractItemView::PositionAtCenter
                         : QAbstractItemView::EnsureVisible);
```

So perhaps if you do the following (not tested here) you might get the result you want:

```
ui->comboBox->addItem("This");
ui->comboBox->addItem("is");
ui->comboBox->addItem("a");
ui->comboBox->addItem("comboBox");

ui->comboBox->setEditable(true);
ui->comboBox->view()->setFocusPolicy(Qt::FocusPolicy::NoFocus); // don't allow focusing of the view of the popup
connect(ui->comboBox, SIGNAL(currentTextChanged(QString)), this, SLOT(PrintTextLineEdit(QString)));

void MainWindow::PrintTextLineEdit(QString str)
{
  ui->comboBox->showPopup();
  ui->comboBox->lineEdit()->setFocus();
}
```

Worth a try.

Comment: This didn't seems to produce any visible effect :(

Comment: Oh wait, you are trying to do this on the QLineEdit of the combobox itself? That's built in functionality. Remove your `currentTextChanged` signal slot and use @heyYo his method.

Comment: No. I am trying to write something in the QLineEdit of the comboBox and when I am doing that I need the popUp to be shown. I opened this question just for that and nothing more. In the current situation every time I write a letter the popUp is shown and I can not further write in the QLineEdit.

Comment: @student, is the following helping you: https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/tools-completer.html

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`QCompleter`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html) feature of [`QLineEdit`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html) may be a better / less hacky solution:

```
QStringListModel *model; // or another QAbstractItemModel
model->setStringList({"This", "is", "a", "combobox"});

QLineEdit *lineEdit;
lineEdit->setCompleter(new QCompleter(model, lineEdit));
lineEdit->completer()->setFilterMode(Qt::MatchContains); // set filter mode as desired
```

A popup will be shown once the user starts editing the line edit. The only disadvantage of this approach is the absence of the drop down icon to show all possible (unfiltered) items.